# Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-login -Facebook login issue

Tags: flutter, facebook, dart, facebook-login

My project was working fine till tomorrow now I'm getting this error in my all projects which have `facebookLogin`.

- **pubspac.yaml**

```
flutter_login_facebook: ^1.6.0
```

- **compileSdkVersion**

  ```
    compileSdkVersion 33
  ```
- **minSdkVersion**

  ```
   minSdkVersion 20
  ```
- **repositories**

  ```
   repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
  ```
- **dependencies**

  ```
  dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
    }
  ```

I'm facing the below error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-login.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Read timed out
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In /android/app/build.gradle, within **dependencies**, change this line

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:15.0.2'
```

This works for me and I can successfully login with facebook.

You might also need to run a "flutter clean" command before building.

Please note!
I'm using flutter_facebook_auth (^5.0.0+2) instead of flutter_login_facebook.

Update!
They just released version 1.6.2 of flutter_login_facebook which addresses your issue, so doing a "flutter pub upgrade" should resolve it.

Comment: But i have 1 concern that what is facebook upgrade it's version then what will happen?

Comment: Try using 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release' again, now that they released version 1.6.2 of flutter_login_facebook . It's best to ensure you have the latest version of the Facebook Android SDK instead of a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:12.3.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I am able to run the app but I'm not able to do a facebook login.